# Function eliminating rows and columns if any of the two are all equal to 0 AND index removed (for sparse matrices) in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to come up with a function which does the following:

1. Take an array (preferably a sparse csr.matrix) N x N
2. Find which rows and/or columns all have 0 entries
3. Remove both the Nth row and the Nth column if any of the two (or both) have all 0 entries
4. Return the new NxN array (or sparse matrix) (with no all-0 entries rows and/or columns) and the index of the removed rows/columns.

I manage to return the correct array, but the return index of the removed rows and columns is not correct (and smaller): this is due to the fact that since I remove rows and columns, it might happen that new rows/columns now become all 0, while they were not before.
Take for example the array: [0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0]. I shall remove the 2nd row and the 2nd column. Now, the new array  [0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,1,1] shall remove both the 1st and 2nd row and columns, which is okay, but it's easy to see how the returned indices are in a sense "scaled", i.e. they are not really the initial ones.

This is the function a created for the moment:

```
def remove_zero_rows(X):
    # X is a scipy sparse matrix. We want to remove all zero rows/columns from it
    creat_list=list(range(0, X.shape[1]))
    
    nonzero_row_indice, nonzero_col_indice = X.nonzero()
    
    unique_nonzero_indice = np.unique(nonzero_row_indice)
    row_ind=np.array(list(set(creat_list).difference(unique_nonzero_indice))) ## Set of row 0s
    
    nonzero_col_indice = np.unique(nonzero_col_indice)
    col_ind=np.array(list(set(creat_list).difference(nonzero_col_indice))) ## Set of cols 0s
    
    merge_two= list(set(row_ind) | set(col_ind)) # This is the index of 0 rows/columns
    #Create new matrix
    
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        if(X.shape[1]-(np.unique(X.nonzero()[0]).size)>0 or X.shape[1]-(np.unique(X.nonzero()[1]).size)>0):
            X = X[np.unique(X.nonzero()[0])][:,np.unique(X.nonzero()[0])]
            X = X[np.unique(X.nonzero()[1])][:,np.unique(X.nonzero()[1])]
            #print(i)
        else:
            break
    
    return X, row_ind, col_ind, merge_two;
```

Thanks you!

Comment: I haven't tried to follow your logic, but it may be a good idea to treat the dense and sparse cases separate.  It's probably easier to get the dense case working - and until the dimensions get very large, faster.  Modifying sparse matrices, even csr, can be expensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot - to be honest it's the first time I use sparse matrices, so not really acquainted with the different trade-offs in using dense vs. sparse. Two issues though: I know already that my matrix will be very large, which is why I had a sliht preference for the sparse case. Also, even in the dense case while the removal is straight-forward, taking into account the "real index", i.e. the initial index of rows and columns which are deleted at tevery step, is not really clear (to me at least).